# How to redirect all requests to HTTPS with SEO friendly URL using Apache?

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

First of all, I would like to <del>leave</del> remove www and redirect all request to HTTPS like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Furthermore, I have to make this URL friendly:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?pg=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I tried to **combine** these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([\w]+) https://%1/index.php?pg=$1 [END,QSA]
```

But it does not work.

For example, I want these URLs to be redirected:

- `http://www.example.com/index.php?p=home`
- `http://example.com/index.php?p=home`
- `http://www.example.com/home`
- `http://example.com/home`

to `https://example.com/home` *(so the user only uses/sees this URL)*

Comment: If by any chance you are using wordpress, you have to change http to https in the relevant section of wp-config file.

Comment: "leave www and redirect all request to https _like this_" - "like this"? Those directives strip the `www` subdomain - but you said you wanted to "leave www"? (However, looking at your examples later it looks like you do want to strip the www, not "leave" it?) "I tried to combine these rules" - if by "combine" you mean _combine_ into a single rule, then you can't do that. These rules need to be kept entirely **separate** - they do entirely different things.

Comment: @deolcarsolutions Thanks, but I don't use any _CMS System_.

Comment: @MrWhite Thank you, it's useful to know how it work. Can you show me an example to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to *combine* these rules

It looks like you are literally trying to combine these rules into a single rule?! These are two very different things:

1. Canonicalise the URL (ie. *remove* the www and redirect to HTTPS). (Although you stated you wanted to "leave www" - your examples and directives suggest the opposite.)
2. Internally rewrite the request.

As such these should be kept as two separate rules. In which case, the rules you currently have should be working OK as they are? Although you have specified `p=` in your URLs, whereas your directive uses `pg=`?

In other words:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Canonicalise the URL - remove www and redirect to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

# Internally rewrite the "pretty" URL
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However, you should be consistent: do your URLs end in a slash or not? The above directive currently allows both - which is potentially *duplicate content*.

> - `http://www.example.com/index.php?p=home`
> - `http://example.com/index.php?p=home`

The next (optional) step is to redirect any direct requests to a URL of the form `/index.php?p=home` (both HTTP and HTTPS, www and non-www) to the "pretty" version `/home`. This is, again, a separate task and requires a separate rule.

To clarify... **you must already be linking to the correct canonical URL in your HTML source.** ie. your links already show `/home` and *not* `/index.php?p=home`.

The additional complexity here is that we only want to redirect direct requests and not rewritten requests by the later rewrite.

The following needs to go *before* the above directives (after the `RewriteEngine` directive):

```
# Redirect "old" URLs to new "pretty" URLs
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([\w-]+)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1 [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The `QSD` flag (Apache 2.4+) is necessary to remove the query string from the redirected URL. (Or can your *old* URLs contain additional URL parameters that need to be passed?)

The condition that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is necessary to prevent a redirect loop.

Change the 302 (temporary) redirect to 301 (permanent) - assuming that is the intention - only when you are sure this is working OK - to avoid caching issues. You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

#### In summary:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect "old" URLs to new "pretty" URLs
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([\w-]+)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1 [QSD,R=302,L]

# Canonicalise the URL - remove www and redirect to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

# Internally rewrite the "pretty" URL
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have any idea why page returns _ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS_? In that case I remove line: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]` page doesn't returns any error (but the rewrite doesn't works well for sure).

Comment: I changed it to `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !http`.

Comment: If testing against `HTTPS` results in a redirect loop, which is fixed by checking against `HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto` instead, then that suggests there is a front-end proxy that is handling the secure connection to the client. The SSL cert is not installed directly on your application server and you are serving plain HTTP to the proxy.